# The "core" of complete Erdős space

Tags: gn.general-topology, dimension-theory, erdos

This question is about the Erdős spaces:

$\mathfrak E=\{x\in \ell^2:x_n\in \mathbb Q\text{ for all $n<\omega$}\}$; and

$\mathfrak E_c=\{x\in \ell^2:x_n\in \mathbb P\text{ for all $n<\omega$}\},$

where $\ell^2$ is the Hilbert space, $\mathbb Q$ is the set of rational numbers, and $\mathbb P=\mathbb R\setminus \mathbb Q$.

I would like to know whether the Polish space $\mathfrak E_c$ contains a homeomorphic copy of either $\mathfrak E$ or $\mathbb Q \times \mathfrak E_c$, such that the complement of that copy is zero-dimensional.

**Question 1.** Let $X\subseteq \mathfrak E_c$ such that $\mathfrak E_c\setminus X$ is zero-dimensional.  Can we have  $X\simeq \mathfrak E$ or $\mathbb Q \times \mathfrak E_c$?

Note that a separable metrizable space $X$ has a completion with zero-dimensional remainder if and only if $X$ is rim-complete [2, Main Theorem (case $n=0$)].

**Question 2.** Are  $\mathfrak E$ and $\mathbb Q\times \mathfrak E_c$ rim-complete?

Note that $\mathbb Q\times \mathfrak E_c$ is a closed subspace of $\mathfrak E$ by [1, Corollary 9.5], so if $\mathfrak E$ is rim-complete then so is $\mathbb Q \times \mathfrak E_c$. 
In the comments Taras Banakh noted that $\mathbb Q \times K$ cannot be rim-complete when $K$ is a compact space of positive dimension.

[1] *Dijkstra, Jan J.; van Mill, Jan*, [**Erdős space and homeomorphism groups of manifolds**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1090/S0065-9266-10-00579-X), Mem. Am. Math. Soc. 979, v, 62 p. (2010). [ZBL1204.57041](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1204.57041).

[2] *Aarts, J. M.*, [**Completeness degree. A generalization of dimension**](http://dx.doi.org/10.4064/fm-63-1-27-41), Fundam. Math. 63, 27-41 (1968). [ZBL0167.51303](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0167.51303).

Comment: Very good question. I tend to believe (but cannot prove) that you Question should have negative answer.

Comment: @TarasBanakh The Lavrentiev approach seems to be more difficult than I previously thought. I think a good sub-question is:  If $X$ is a Polish space of positive dimension, and $G$ is a $G_\delta$-subset of $\mathbb R\times X$ containing $\mathbb Q \times X$, then is the dimension of $G\setminus(\mathbb Q \times X)$ necessarily positive?

Comment: If $X$ is compact, then the answer to the subquestion is yes.

Comment: I have no reference, but the argument is quite simple: If a Polish space $X$ contains a topological copy of $\mathbb Q\times K$ for some compact space $K$, then $X\setminus (\mathbb Q\times K)$ contains a topological copy of $K$. Using the Lavrentiev Theorem we can reduce the problem to the case $X\subset \mathbb I\times K$, where $\mathbb I$ is a compactification of $\mathbb Q$. Then $S=(\mathbb I\times K)\setminus X$ is a $\sigma$-compact subset of $\mathbb I\times K$ and so is its projection $pr(S)$ to $\mathbb I$.

Comment: The Baire Theorem implies that $\mathbb I\setminus\mathbb Q$ is not $\sigma$-compact and hence there exists $x\in\mathbb I\setminus\mathbb Q$ such that $x\notin pr(S)$ and hence $\{x\}\times K\subset X$.

Comment: Maybe given any bounded open subset of $\mathfrak E$ we can find a closed copy of $\mathbb Q$ in its boundary?

Comment: No, the boundary of any open bounded set in the Erdos space is uncountable.

Comment: And the space $\mathbb Q\times \mathfrak E_c$ indeed has a basis consisting of open sets with Polish boundaries.

Comment: @TarasBanakh also about $\mathbb Q$, I was only talking about a closed subset of the boundary.  For instance, the rectangular open sets in $\mathbb Q\times \mathfrak E_c$ have closed copies of $\mathbb Q$ in their boundaries.

Comment: @TarasBanakh I still do not see why $\mathbb Q\times \mathfrak E_c$ is rim-complete.  Did you mean rim-$\sigma$-complete or am I missing some small detail?

Comment: Ups! You right concerning the boundaries, Rectangular sets indeed have copies of $\mathbb Q$ in their boundaries. But maybe Baire Theorem will help: assuming that some bounded (canonically) open set in $\mathbb Q\times \mathfrak C_c$ has Polish boundary, decompose it into countably many slices and find a " locally isolated" slice  and then derive a contradiction with canonical openness, Maybe this way?

Comment: @TarasBanakh Yes, or maybe it is possible in $\mathfrak E$ to take a closed copy of $\mathbb Q$ in the bounded open set, and "move" it to a closed (or at least $G_\delta$) copy of $\mathbb Q$ in the boundary.

Comment: @TarasBanakh Another idea: Given a bounded open set in $\mathfrak E$, and a $G_\delta$-set $G\subseteq \mathfrak E_c$ containing its boundary, show $G$ contains a point with irrational coordinates.

Comment: But you consider $\mathfrak E$ as embedded into $\mathfrak E_c$ (by an ``irrational shift"). Right?

Comment: I have an idea how to prove what you need: just apply Kuratowski-Ulam Theorem on meager sections (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kuratowski%E2%80%93Ulam_theorem)!

Comment: Unfortunately, at the moment I should prepare slides for tomorrow's presentation, so I cannot write the solution immediately. Please wait just a bit.

Comment: Unfortunately, my approach using Kuratowski-Ulam does not work. But nonetheless I believe (without proof yet) that $\mathbb Q\times\mathfrak E_c$ cannot be rim-complete.

Comment: @TarasBanakh Well thanks for trying. It seems to be a very tricky problem, and it may even be one of those cases where our intuition is wrong.

Comment: @TarasBanakh These questions are so simple but I am still struggling to make heads or tails of them.  Very frustrating.

Comment: Would you define -- pretty please -- "rim-complete"?

Comment: @WlodAA It means there is a basis of open sets with completely metrizable (absolute $G_\delta$) boundaries. Don't know if any other terms exist for this.

Comment: Thank you. (These definitions get sophisticated).

Comment: It seems that your question reduces (at least in one direction) to the problem: let $\gamma:C\to[0,1]$ be an upper semicontinuous function on the Cantor set $C$ whose graph $\Gamma$ is a complete Erdos space. Is there a countable subset $Q\subset [0,1]$ without isolated points such that $(Q\times C)\cap\Gamma$ is Polish?

Comment: @TarasBanakh What do you mean by $(Q\times C)\cap \Gamma$?  Also if $\Gamma$ is homeomorphic to $\mathfrak E_c$ then the domain of $\gamma$ has to be first category.  The domain cannot be compact, but there is a $\sigma$-compact subset  $S\subseteq C$ such that $\mathfrak E_c$ is the graph of a USC function $\gamma:S\to[0,1]$.

Comment: Maybe you just mean $\Gamma$ is the *positive* graph in $C\times [0,1]$, and you want to know if $(C\times Q)\cap \Gamma$ is Polish?

Comment: @D.S.Lipham I had in mind the complete Erdos space, modeled as the set of end-points of the Lelek fan. The Lelek fan with removed origin can be seen as the hypograph of an upper semicontinuous function on the Cantor set, and the end-points of the Lelek fan then lie on the graph $\Gamma$ of this upper semi-continuous function. Because of that, the complete Erdos space can be identified with the graph of this upper semicontinuous function. Am I right with this description?

Comment: Essentially yes.  $\gamma$ is sometimes called a Lelek function. $\Gamma\setminus (C\times \{0\})$ is complete Erdos space. The complement of the zero-set of $\gamma$ is $\sigma$-compact and first category.

Comment: @TarasBanakh Do you think it is true that if $X$ is a zero-dimensional subset of the graph of a USC function $\varphi:C\to [0,\infty)$, then $\mathbb R\times(0,\infty)\setminus X$ is  path-connected?  This would imply negative answers to all questions above (and it is weaker than my recent conjecture in: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/361671/zero-dimensional-functions-in-the-plane).